# Converting SQL to LINQ to hit database once

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, ormlite-servicestack

How can I convert the following T-SQL query to LINQ?

```
SELECT * FROM "VwBusinessUnits"
                WHERE "BusinessUnitName" in (
                    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10 "BusinessUnitName"
                    FROM "VwBusinessUnits"
                    WHERE("StateOrProvince" = 'QLD')
                    ORDER BY "BusinessUnitName"
                )
```

I have this solution which is working, however it is doing two hits to the DB, I'd prefer to have just one like the T-SQL query above:

```
SqlExpression<VwBusinessUnits> distinctBusinessUnitNamesSqlExpression = db.From<VwBusinessUnits>()
                .Where(x => x.StateOrProvince.ToUpper() == "QLD")
                .OrderBy(x => x.BusinessUnitName)
                .SelectDistinct(x => x.BusinessUnitName)
                .Take(take);

            var distinctBusinessUnitNames = db.Select(distinctBusinessUnitNamesSqlExpression).Select(x => x.BusinessUnitName);

            SqlExpression<VwBusinessUnits> sqlExpression = db.From<VwBusinessUnits>()
                .Where(x => distinctBusinessUnitNames.Contains(x.BusinessUnitName));

            List<VwBusinessUnits> businessUnits = db.Select(sqlExpression);
```

**Update:**

`db` is an instance of `System.Data.IDbConnection` and I'm using extension methods in `ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactoryExtensions`

I got it to work using this:

```
            string sql = @"SELECT * FROM VwBusinessUnits 
                            WHERE BusinessUnitName in 
                            (SELECT DISTINCT TOP {0} BusinessUnitName
                            FROM VwBusinessUnits 
                            WHERE(StateOrProvince = @state))";
            int take = 10;
            string state = "QLD";                
            List<VwBusinessUnits> businessUnits = db.SqlList<VwBusinessUnits(string.Format(sql, take), new { state });
```

I couldn't pass `take` as an @ parameter like state, for some reason it said

> Incorrect syntax near @take

There's no risk of SQL injection attacks because the take parameter is an `int`.

If anyone finds a way to do this in LINQ instead of a hardcoded SQL query, please let me know.

Comment: Give a try to `List<VwBusinessUnits> businessUnits = db.ExecuteQuery<List<VwBusinessUnits>>(YOUR SQL QUERY);`

Comment: @GaurangDave There's no ExecuteQuery method. The closest thing I could find was ExecuteSql() but that returns an int.

Comment: There is `ExecuteQuery` method in `System.Data.Linq` namespace. I used it many times. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery?view=netframework-4.7.2) for more details.

Comment: @GaurangDave db is an instance of System.Data.IDbConnection, not DataContext

Answer (score 1):

So you have a table: `VwBusinessUnits` where every `VwBusinessUnit` has at least properties `BusinessUnitName`, and a `StateOrProvince`

Alas you forgot to tell us your requirements, but from your SQL statement it seems that you want all properties from all `VwBusinessUnits` that have a name that would appear in the following sequence:

> The first 10 `BusinessUnitNames` of `VwBusinessUnits` that would result if you would take the `BusinessUnitNames` from all `VwBuisinessUnits` that have a `StateOrProvince` that equals `QLD` by by `BusinessUnitName`, and order these names.

This is a wordy way to say:

- take the collection of `VwBusinessUnits`,
- keep only those with a `StateOrProvince` equal to `QLD`.
- Extract the `BusinessUnitName`
- Order ascending
- Take the first 10

The query for this would be something like:

```
var collectionOfNames = myDbContext.VwBusinessUnits
    .Where(vwBusinessUnit => vwBusinessUnit.Name == "QLD")
    .Select(vwBusinessUnit => vwBusinessUnitName)
    .OrderBy(name => name)
    .Take(10);
```

Note: you've only made an IQueryable object, it is not executed yet. Only the `Expression` of the queryable has been filled.

You main query is something like this:

- We have a sequence of business unit names
- take all `VwBusinessUnits`
- keep only those `VwBusinessUnits` with a `BusinessUnitName` in the sequence of business unit names

The query is something like:

```
var result = myDbContext.VwBusinessUnits
    .Where(vwBusinessUnit => collectionOfNames.Contains(vwBusinessUnit.Name));
```

You can keep these queries separate, or make one big lump of a query. Because they are still queries this won't speed up your process. However it makes it less readable, testable, maintainable:

```
var result = myDbContext.VwBusinessUnits
    .Where(vwBusinessUnit => 
        myDbContext.VwBusinessUnits
            .Where(vwBusinessUnit => vwBusinessUnit.Name == "QLD")
            .Select(vwBusinessUnit => vwBusinessUnitName)
            .OrderBy(name => name)
            .Take(10)
            .Contains(vwBusinessUnit.Name));
```

### Problem in your query

Your inner query has some problems if your `BusinessUnitNames` are not unique.

Suppose you have a very large collection of `VwBusinnessUnits`: millions of them. Ten of these `VwBusinessUnits have a name like "AAAAAAAAAA". If you would order all names of all millions`VwBusinessUnits` you would end with a sequence of 10 times the same "AAAAAAAAA", which is as if you only selected the top 1

If you want to be sure there are exactly 10 different names, even if several companies have the same name, consider using `Distinct` before `OrderBy` and `Take(10)`

Comment: the db instance doesn't have a member called VwBusinessUnits.

Comment: Well your own code says: `FROM VwBusinessUnits`, so I assumed you have a table with this name. If you don't provide the interface with your database we'll have to guess about identifier names. If you have problems re-interpreting incorrectly guessed identifiers, maybe you should pay more attention in providing us the interface with your database the next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like this:

```
var innerQuery = db.BusinessUnits
    .Where(x => x.StateOrProvince.ToUpper() == "QLD")
    .Select(x => x.BusinessUnitName)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(x => x)
    .Take(take);
```

at this point we have an IQueryable that can be used as subquery:

```
var outerQuery = db.VwBusinessUnits
    .Where(x => innerQuery.Contains(x.BusinessUnitName));
var data = outerQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: db.VwBusinessUnits and db.BusinessUnits don't compile, they are not members of the instance db.

Answer (score 0):

Following Linq query will be helpful to you,

```
List<VwBusinessUnits> businessUnits = db.VwBusinessUnits
                                      .Where( y => (
                                                     db.VwBusinessUnits
                                                     .Where(x => x.StateOrProvince== "QLD")
                                                     .OrderBy(x => x.BusinessUnitName)                                         
                                                     .Select(x=>x.BusinessUnitName)
                                                     .Distinct()
                                                     .Take(take)
                                                   ).Contains(y.BusinessUnitName)
                                             ).ToList()
```

Comment: db.VwBusinessUnits doesn't compile, there is no member called VwBusinessUnits